# How To Build a Operating System With C#

Tags: c#, osdev

I was reading about [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/) and it was developed in part with C#, but how can I develop a operatin system in part with C#?(because the boot loader needs to be in Assembly, that I know) the thing that I want to know is where to start(tutorial, library...)?

PS: Congratulations to the Singularity developers, very nice job! ;)

Comment: The question is way too broad. You might want rephrase in such a way that someone who has a clue will be able to give you a useful answer in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: The question cannot be satisfactorily answered in its present form.  It is at once too broad and too narrow.  I'd suggest rephrasing the question to either be for one specific thing or for general introductions to OS design and instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Renraku](http://daeken.com/renraku-future-os) is an open source project to create an OS using .NET technologies as much as possible. [This post](http://daeken.com/renraku-it-lives) has a link to the source on GitHub.

Comment: But there is some tutorials about this?

Comment: I don't think so, it's a nascent open source project but may be instructive for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just because you write your program in c# it doesn't have to be compiled to IL. Writing a c# to machine code compiler can be done and last time I saw an OS written in C# that was exactly what they had done

Answer (score 2):

The major difference between an operating system that runs on managed code vs. one that runs directly on machine code is really nothing more than having a byte-code interpreter at a very low level that processes all byte code sent to it and translates to the corresponding machine code. Once that exists, the various operating system components would be implemented in pretty much the same way as they would in a traditional OS.