# OS(Operating System) Programming in C#

Tags: c#, osdev

I know this project.The question is that "Can we create a real OS with Managed Code or the os that will create with this project is a hello world os?"
Operating Systems need to have full control on hardware.Can we do it with this one?
If there are any another project please tell me
[Cosmos Project](http://www.gocosmos.org)

Comment: Are you asking if there are any managed code operating systems out there? Check out the [Singularity project](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/), from Microsoft.

Comment: I know that there are.But can we write a big os such as mac os or windows with these projects???

Comment: @LightWing: it's a daunting task. First of all, Singularity is an OS, so you can't write an OS with it. I know Microsoft uses a language similar to C# to write it, but I don't have any more details.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about MOSA,But Cosmos is a project for c#.Net to develop OS

Comment: Of course you can build an operating system in a managed environment. It all depends how you define operating system.

Comment: No point in re-opening this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669993/how-to-build-a-operating-system-with-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058876/a-full-operating-system-in-c plus the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/861257/2509 discusses the possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can be done - see [Singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29) which is (was) a Microsoft research project to create an entirely managed operating system in "Sing#" (an extended version of "Spec#" which is itself an extension of C#).  *Its worth stressing that this was just a research project into the concept, and was never intended as a "full" operating system of the likes of Windows or Max OSX.*

The source code is available on [CodePlex](http://singularity.codeplex.com/) - you can download the code, build it and run it yourself in an  emulator (I've done it myself, its well documented and relativley easy although I can't remember the exact steps myself).

Parts of the system were written in assembly / C, specifically the bootloader and the lowest level x86 interupt dispatch code however this is essentially all but unavoidable (it is by its very nature very platform dependant - *something* needs to write the x86 instructions to control and respond to basic hardware).  The low level interrupts are also not particularly interesting in terms of how the operating system actually functions, so I personally don't consider this as cheating the "entirely managed" definition.

Looking on the Wikipedia page for Singularity there are also 5-6 similar projects, including Cosmos and a couple of similar attempts that use Java instead of C#.

The focus of Singularity OS was on security and dependency, however whats also impressive is that according to some basic benchmarks in [An Overview of the Singularity Project1 (PDF)](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDEQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fpubs%2F52716%2Ftr-2005-135.pdf&ei=qMvQTaveJ4jUtQPx3vHFCw&usg=AFQjCNEDhrjA6V3Wbx1oaPPJm0kjaFkZdw) the performance of their archetecture was actually comparable to that of other "more conventional" operating systems:

> ... these numbers demonstrate that architecture that we
>   proposed not only does not incur a performance penalty, but is often as fast as or faster than more
>   conventional architecture. In other words, it is a practical basis on which to build a system.

Comment: I think a managed operating system is so great.but performance.

Comment: Is it open source,if no , is there an open source equal

Comment: @LightWing I don't know if it is "Open source" (it is just a research project not a "proper" OS) however the source code is available on CodePlex.

Comment: I have no idea what performance was like but it wasn't the focus of their research so it probably wasn't fantastic, however I'm not aware of any real reason why it shouldn't be able to perform if enough effort was spent optimising it suitably.

Comment: if understand it,os programming in java seems interesting too.http://www.jnode.org/ Thanks your link to Wikipedia was so great.